# vscode insert newline between objects of python print statement

Tags: printing, visual-studio-code, console, newline

I encountered a weird setting problem of vscode with python. 
I am now using vscode and python to develop apps that can run both in Win 10 and macOS. 
Yesterday I copied all code from win10 in a PC to macOS in a macbook. 
Then I made some changes in macOS and copied everything back to win10 since I need to trouble-shooting some bugs by my win10 users. 
I am sure that I only copied the source code of my modules without copying the vscode setting.
But I found now in vscode in win10, print statement to the vscode console automatically adds two newlines between each object in the print statement argument list. 
I found that I can use option sep="" to avoid one newline.  But one newline persists between every two arguments.
This problem does not occur when I run the python program in win10 console. 
I will appreciate it someone can let me know what has happened and how to correct this anomaly of vscode.

Thank you very much.